# GNU scientific library for sparse and complex matrices

Tags: c, sparse-matrix, complex-numbers, gsl

> Am I correct in saying that GNU scientific library (GSL), in its present form, can not be used for solving a linear system involving sparse and *complex* matrices?

I am not very good with C, but I find I can't create a sparse matrix containing complex values with GSL's `gsl_spmatrix` function. I use

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_spmatrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_complex_math.h>

gsl_spmatrix * re_A ;
gsl_spmatrix * im_A ;
void createspmatrix_c (int n)
{ 
  re_A = gsl_spmatrix_alloc (n,n);  
  im_A = gsl_spmatrix_alloc (n,n);        
 }
```

So, I created sparse matrices to store real and imaginary parts of the data separately. At best I can populate these sparse matrices with data created elsewhere. My objective then is to be able to use GMRES with `gsl_splinalg_itersolve_gmres` in GSL but can't see how i can use it. Looking at `gsl_spmatrix.h`, I see

```
typedef struct
{
  size_t size1;  /* number of rows */
  size_t size2;  /* number of columns */

  /* i (size nzmax) contains:
   *
   * Triplet/CCS: row indices
   * CRS: column indices
   */
 size_t *i;

 double *data; /* matrix elements of size nzmax */
 // some more lines...
 } gsl_spmatrix;
```

The matrix elements are required to be of type `double`. 
So likely the `gsl_spmatrix` structure is available only for `real` matrices.